# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n^2}}{3n^2+2}e^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

> Does this series converge? I have tried many methods that I know.
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n^2}}{3n^2+2}e^n$$

Edit : after I saw the comments, I tried the ratio method that someone here told me. did I do it right?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what method(s) you have tried which leads to inconclusive result?

Comment: How do the 3 parts of the expression, $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}$, $\frac{1}{3n^2+2}$, and $e^n$, grow?

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test that is to say test if the limit when $n \ rightarrow \infty$ of $|u_{n+1/u_n}|$ is large than 1 ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually the ratio test is inconclusive.

Comment: "I have tried many methods that I know" Indeed, explaining at least one of these "many methods" seems requested.

Comment: @JeanMarie can u plz check the update of the question ,did i check the ratio well?

Comment: It seems we will never know the nature of the famous "many methods"...

Comment: @YardenSharabi What does the ratio test say? If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n >1$, then the series is divergent; if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n<1$, then the series is convergent; if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n =1$, then try with a different method.

Comment: To unearth an argument that is somewhat buried in the comment thread below, I mention that the elementary inequality $$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\leqslant\frac1e$$ shows that the $n$th term of this positive series is at most $$\frac1{3n^2+2}$$ hence the series converges. More generally, if some series $$\sum_nx_n$$ converges absolutely then the series $$\sum_nx_n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n^2}e^n$$  converges absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is a series with positive terms, hence it is enough to show that it is bounded above.

The key is:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1- \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2} e^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$
in particular, the sequence $\left( 1- \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2} e^n$ is convergent, hence it is bounded above by some constant $C > 0$.

Now, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1- \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2} e^n \frac{1}{3n^2+2} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{C}{3n^2+2} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{C}{n^2} < +\infty$$
so that your series is convergent by the comparison test.

Comment: If the OP knew this limit, my guess is they would not ask the question. Oh, and the limit is false...

Comment: And... did you also get that to produce this limit without explanation is basically to take the answer for granted?

Comment: @Did OK, now the limit is correct. Thanks for having pointed me this. Actually I have no other idea to show that the sequence is bounded above... But knowing that limit it is evident that the terms are $O( \frac{1}{n^2} )$, so comparison test here seems the unique way to conclude. If the asker wants deeper explanations about that limit, I will give them.

Comment: Not sure I got your explanations about how to get the exact limit. Fortunately this is not needed to solve the question: the (simple to prove) inequality $1-\frac1n\leqslant e^{-1/n}$ shows that $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n^2}e^n\leqslant1$, which is all one needs to conclude.

Comment: actully, if I knew the limit I woulden't needed help, thank u anyway.

Comment: @Crostul The limit $\sqrt{e}$ is wrong (and not needed).

Comment: @Did I made a sign mistake... Now the limit is correct.

Comment: Now the limit is correct. Remains that you do not explain how you found it and that, imho, any user able to compute this limit on their own would not ask this question.